# (how does n = (l-a/d)+1

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

So I was introduced to sequences and series in my class and understood each and every formula but couldn't understand n = ((l-a)/d)+1 where l = last term , a = first term and d = common difference in an arithmetic progression.please be easy on me.

Comment: Well, actually the formula should have $\frac{l-a}{d}+1$, not $l-\frac{a}{d}+1$ (assuming $a=c_1$ and $l=c_n$)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that there are $n$ terms, starting with $a$ and having common difference $d$; then the terms are

$$a,a+d,a+2d,a+3d,\ldots,a+(n-1)d\;.$$

Why $n-1$ and not $n$? The $1$-st term in that list is $a+0d$, the $2$-nd term is $a+1d$, the $3$-rd term is $a+2d$, and in general the $k$-th term is $a+(k-1)d$. Thus, the $n$-th term is $a+(n-1)d$.

To put it a little differently, if we call the terms $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$, to get from $a_1$ to $a_n$ we have to add $d$ once for each term from $a_2$ through $a_n$, and there are $n-1$ of them.

Thus, the last term must actually be $\ell=a+(n-1)d$, and therefore

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\ell-a}d+1&=\frac{\big(a+(n-1)d\big)-a}d+1\\
&=\frac{(n-1)d}d+1\\
&=(n-1)+1\\
&=n\;.
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

In an A.P. containing n terms, we can construct an expression for the last term in the sequence. Using your notation,

$$l = a + (n-1)d.$$

You can see why this is true by applying it to an actual sequence, say  $2,5,8,11,\dots$

By rearranging the above equation, we then obtain $n = \frac{l-a}{d}+1$.

EDIT:
Rearranging:
$$ \begin{align} l-a &= (n-1)d \\
 \frac{l-a}{d} &= n-1 \\
n &= \frac{l-a}{d}+1 \end{align}$$

Comment: Well i could understand the (l-a)/d part but just couldn't understand the +1 part .just why is it there?

Comment: @Kunal_Boss Does this clear things up? Let me know if anything is still unclear

Comment: well i am doubtful in the addition of 1 part what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Kunal_Boss Are you referring to my edit? The +1 in the last step is merely a rearranging of the terms from the previous line. The objective here is to obtain an expression for n in terms of $l,a,d$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\underbrace{0\,\overbrace{\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0\cdots\cdots0}^{l-a}}_{n\ {\rm terms}\ \ \therefore\ \ n-1\ {\rm gaps\ of\ size}\ d}$$

Comment: Hey i am just a 10th grader and i don't understand your answer can you simplify it.

Comment: Visualise what an AP looks like - equal gaps between the terms.

Comment: Ok i think i sound pretty elementary , but if I subtract two numbers

Comment: does the answer includes the second number or the first number eg:-  8-2 = 6 is 8 included or 2 is included. dont be angry with me i am just starting to see the beauty of math.

Comment: Look carefully at how I have placed the upper bracket.  The first number is excluded but all the others including the last are included.  Eg $8-2=6$ tells you that there are six numbers from $2$ to $8$, excluding the $2$ and including the $8$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ denote the sum of all the terms in the arithmetic progression.

Clearly,

\begin{align} 
S &= a + (a+d) + (a+2d) + \hspace{2mm}... \hspace{2mm}+ (a + (n-1)d) \hspace{40mm} [1] \\
S &= 0 + \hspace{2mm} a  \hspace{9mm} + (a + \hspace{2mm}d)  + \hspace{2mm} ... \hspace{2mm} + \hspace{1mm}(a + (n-2)d) + (a + (n-1)d) \hspace{6mm} [2]\\
\end{align}

Subtracting $[2]$ from $[1]$, we have:
\begin{align}
0 &= a + d + d \hspace{1mm}+ \hspace{2mm} ... + \hspace{1mm} d \hspace{1mm} - (a + (n-1)d) \\
  &= a + (n-1)d - l
\end{align}
Where $l$ denotes the last term in the arithmetic progression.
Hence, the equation now becomes:
\begin{align}
(n-1)*d &= (l-a) \\
(n-1) &= (l-a)/d \\
n &= (l-a)/d + 1
\end{align}